# Continuity Question, proving epsilon-delta

Tags: limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Question:

> Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function at the point $x_0$ and that $f(x_0) \neq 0$.  Using the $\epsilon−\delta$ definition of the continuity of a function at $x_0$, show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$f(x_0) \neq 0 \ {whenever}\ |x-x_0| < \delta \ and \ x\in[a,b] $$

My thoughts are we use the defintion as stated in the question :

$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0| < \delta$
and then we can use the triangle inequality "$|a-b|| \geq ||a| - |b||$" and then use the fact that $f(x_0) \neq 0 $ and then when we balance the inequality we get that $\epsilon - f(x_0) \neq 0 $ which we can say that it is $\neq 0$

If someone could guide me through how to complete this quesition to the end, it would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: First, apply the definition of continuity with $\epsilon=|f(x_0)|/2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I did so, then what would we do next - use the triangle inequality as in the question or the original inequality but with $b = (-f(x_0))$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose WLOG that $f(x_0)\lt 0$ so that $-f(x_0)\gt 0$ 
Since $f$ is continuous at $x=x_0$, it follows that for every $\epsilon\gt 0,\exists \delta_\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $|x-x_0|\lt \delta_\epsilon\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt \epsilon$. Choose $\epsilon = -f(x_0)$ and hence by continuity of $f$ at $x_0$, there exists a $\delta\gt 0$ such that

$\begin{align}|x-x_0|\lt \delta 
&\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt -f(x_0)\\
&\implies f(x_0)\lt f(x)-f(x_0)\lt -f(x_0)\\
&\implies 2f(x_0)\lt f(x)\lt 0\\
&\implies \text{$f(x)\ne0$ for $x:|x-x_0|\lt \delta$}\end{align}$

Similarly, prove for $f(x_0)\gt 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Ian: You are welcome :)